# How can I avoid the shell script from automatically adding single quotes?

Tags: shell, sh

Here is my example shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#assuming this param is obtained from outside
cmd='-c "python test.py --log_level=info"'

#full cmd
docker run xxx $cmd
```

The expected command should be

```
docker run xxx -c "python test.py --log_level=info"
```

however, error occurs:
test.py: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

So I run with 'sh -x' and here is output:

```
+ cmd='-c "python test.py --log_level=info"'
+ docker run xxx -c '"python' test.py '--log_level=info"'
```

The full cmd is not I wondered, can you help me to solve this? Big thanks :)

Comment: long time forgot to update my question, I solved by adding `eval` at the beginning of cmd :)

Answer (score 0):

First make it easy for yourself by testing with an easier command, eg `ls -- $cmd`

Second, since you're using bash and not just the posix shell, use arrays!

```
cmd=(-c "python test.py --log_level=info")
ls -- "${cmd[@]}"
/bin/ls: cannot access '-c': No such file or directory
/bin/ls: cannot access 'python test.py --log_level=info': No such file or directory
```

See?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, there is no need double quotes in your `cmd`, just `cmd='-c python test.py --log_level=info'`.

In [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), the `-c` is an **OPTION** which means `CPU shares (relative weight)`.

Maybe you want to exec `docker run xxx sh -c ...`, so the script should looks like:

```
cmd='sh -c python test.py --log_level=info'
docker run xxx $cmd
```